# What does this summary data mean?

Tags: r, data-mining, linear-regression

I am using sample algae data to understand data mining a bit more, i have used the following commands:

```
> data(algae)
> algae <- algae[-manyNAs(algae),]
> clean.algae <-knnImputation(algae, k = 10)
> lm.a1 <- lm(a1 ~ ., data = clean.algae[, 1:12])
> summary(lm.a1)
```

Subsequently i received the below results, however i can not find any good documentation which explains what moost of this means, especially Std. Error,t value and Pr. Can someone please be kind enough to shed some light please? Most importantly which variables should i look at to ascertain on whether a model is giving me good prediction data?

```
Call:
lm(formula = a1 ~ ., data = clean.algae[, 1:12])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-37.679 -11.893  -2.567   7.410  62.190 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  42.942055  24.010879   1.788  0.07537 . 
seasonspring  3.726978   4.137741   0.901  0.36892   
seasonsummer  0.747597   4.020711   0.186  0.85270   
seasonwinter  3.692955   3.865391   0.955  0.34065   
sizemedium    3.263728   3.802051   0.858  0.39179   
sizesmall     9.682140   4.179971   2.316  0.02166 * 
speedlow      3.922084   4.706315   0.833  0.40573   
speedmedium   0.246764   3.241874   0.076  0.93941   
mxPH         -3.589118   2.703528  -1.328  0.18598   
mnO2          1.052636   0.705018   1.493  0.13715   
Cl           -0.040172   0.033661  -1.193  0.23426   
NO3          -1.511235   0.551339  -2.741  0.00674 **
NH4           0.001634   0.001003   1.628  0.10516   
oPO4         -0.005435   0.039884  -0.136  0.89177   
PO4          -0.052241   0.030755  -1.699  0.09109 . 
Chla         -0.088022   0.079998  -1.100  0.27265   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 17.65 on 182 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3731,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3215 
F-statistic: 7.223 on 15 and 182 DF,  p-value: 2.444e-12
```

Comment: Hi There, there is a good chance this question will be closed since it does not really pertain to programming in `R` but rather these are just general statistics questions.  A good place to start would be an intro to statistics course such as [this one at Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/stats1) or [this one from Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/st101)

Comment: I honestly think it is a valid question and can help many members here who are also keen to learn about data mining

Comment: it's by no means a bad question. It is a perfectly fine question.  But it is a fine question about statistics.  This question is independent of any programming.  In other words:   `P(ThisQuestion | R) == P(ThisQuestion | SAS) == P(ThisQuestion)`     Perhaps you'd like to migrate this question to stats.stackexchange.com -- many of the people here are also active on that board

Comment: See `?summary.lm`. It will give you the right keywords to google or ask about on a more appropriate forum, http://stats.stackexchange.com is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I can answer this in a good extent, but I would like to try.

With the formula (this specific ~.) you are trying to predict a1 with all other variables in a model of the kind:

```
a1 = b0 + b1*seasonspring + b2*seasonsummer ... + e
```

where b0 is the intercept, and e is the error. The column estimate are the "b" regression coefficients, the t-test and p-values are trying to say if this coefficients are statiscally significant. For example, we could read one of the lines of the table like this

> `NO3` has a linear relationship that helps to predict `a1`, and the b_x coefficient of NO3 is significant with a probability smaller than `0.001` of being equal to zero (roughly speaking).

One of the statistics used to measure the goodness of fit is the R^2

```
R-squared:  0.3731
```

Tha is trying to say, "how  much of the data variance my model explains (again, roughly)", in this case it is very bad, from 0 to 1 only 0.37. There are better measures, this requires a bit of reading...

You can find a detailed explanation here
http://www.manning.com/kabacoff/

Comment: thanks a lot this helped me understand the summary to a certain degree!